# Pandas: Improve function for assigning values based on row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, jupyter-notebook

I am analyzing medical data and want to group case reports by ICD blocks of classification (see here for ref - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ICD-9_codes). I already extracted most of the data I need using Jupyter Notebook. `Primarydata.head().to_dict()` looks like this:

```
{'Patient Name': 
    {0: 'Joe Mok',
      1: 'Ronaldo Gulapa',
      2: 'Judy Undialu',
      3: 'Hinawai Valentina Miabe',
      4: 'Harry Gubala'},
 'Patient Age': {0: 53.0, 1: 55.0, 2: 36.0, 3: 3.0, 4: 47.0},
 'Sex': {0: 'Male', 1: 'Male', 2: 'Female', 3: 'Female', 4: 'Male'},
 'Start Date': {0: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'),
      1: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'),
      2: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'),
      3: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'),
      4: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00')},
 'Staff': {0: 'Dr Daniel Paulino',
      1: 'Dr Daniel Paulino',
      2: 'Dr Daniel Paulino',
      3: 'Dr Daniel Paulino',
      4: 'Dr Leo Reginaldo'},
 'Primary Diagnosis': {0: '47800 - OTHR DISEASES UPPER RESPIRATORY TRACT',
      1: '53550 - GASTRITIS/DUODENITIS NOS',
      2: '72910 - MYALGIA AND MYOSITIS NOS',
      3: '48500 - BRONCHOPNEUMONIA,ORGANISM UNSPECIFIED',
      4: '00930 - DIARRHEA OF INFECT ORIG'}}
```

In this example, the ICD code for the first patient , 47800, will fall under block 460-519 for respiratory diseases. Bear in mind, some values are empty, or not in the wanted format (will have basic descriptions like 'fever'). Beforehand I replaced NaN values with 'none'.

I wrote some code and a function that takes a str input and does the job. But frankly I don't think I used best practice and want to avoid using a long list of if-else statements if possible. so I want to see if I can improve it further or at least have less lines of code. Here's my function:

```
def assign_icd_block(code):
    if code[0] == "E":
        return "E800-E999"
    elif code[0] == "V":
        return "V01-V82"
    elif code.isnumeric():
        icd_value = int(code)
        if (icd_value >= 1) and (icd_value <= 139):
            return "001-139"
        elif (icd_value >= 140) and (icd_value <= 239):
            return "140-239"
        elif (icd_value >= 240) and (icd_value <= 279):
            return "240-279"
        ....
    else:
        return "misc"
```

I looped through all rows within the 'primary diagnosis' column assign each row a ICD block value:

```
ICD_block = []
for index in range(0, len(primary_data)):
    if primary_data["Primary Diagnosis"][index] == "none":
        ICD_block.append("none")
    else:
        icd_value = str(primary_data["Primary Diagnosis"][index])[:3]
        ICD_block.append(assign_icd_block(icd_value))
primary_data["ICD Block"] = ICD_block
```

Can anyone suggest betters ways of writing my code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you include the output of `print(primary_data.head().to_dict())`

Comment: I'd recommend reading on `np.where`/`np.select` and `pd.cut`.

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks! I'm looking into np.select